# String Split After Second Space Character

Tags: java, android, regex

I have a string that I download from JSOUP that looks like

> Paul Millsap Al Horford Tiago Splitter Jeff Teague Kyle Korver Thabo Sefolosha Mike Scott Shelvin Mack Kent Bazemore Dennis Schröder Tim Hardaway Jr. Walter Tavares Justin Holiday Mike Muscala Lamar Patterson Terran Petteway

I want to split it into an array for use in a list view, so the desired output would be:

> Paul Millsap, Al Horford, Tiago Splitter, Jeff Teague, Kyle Korver, Thabo Sefolosha, Mike Scott, Shelvin Mack, Kent Bazemore, Dennis Schröder, Tim Hardaway Jr., Walter Tavares, Justin Holiday, Mike Muscala, Lamar Patterson, Terran Petteway,

How can I do this? Thanks for any help.

Comment: Not possible. It isn't a simple "split every two space" problem. Take "Tim Hardaway Jr" for example... How did you obtain that String in the first place?

Comment: You said you used JSOUP. Didn't that HTML structure already had these names somehow separated? Maybe it is worth checking.

Comment: If not, then get the list in a structured format such as at https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/2014–15_Atlanta_Hawks_season and use Jsoup to extract the cell values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Preferred answer:**

Since you are parsing page which have nice table and you want to get values from specific columns (names of players which are also links) you can do it easily with:

```
String url = "http://www.spotrac.com/nba/atlanta-hawks/cap/";
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
Elements players = doc.select("table.datatable td.player a");
for (Element player : players){
    System.out.println(player.text());
}
```

which will:

- find `table` tag with class `datatable` then inside
- then from that table we select `td.player` which represents each cell `td` element with class `player`
- finally we want to pick these cells which have links `a` (since names are links)

---

**Original answer:**

Based only on example data from your question, you could try to find `OneWord[space]SecondWord(optional:[space]Jr.)`.

Code based on this idea could look like:

```
String input = " Paul Millsap Al Horford Tiago Splitter Jeff Teague Kyle Korver Thabo Sefolosha Mike Scott Shelvin Mack Kent Bazemore Dennis Schröder Tim Hardaway Jr. Walter Tavares Justin Holiday Mike Muscala Lamar Patterson Terran Petteway";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\w+\\s+\\w+(\\s+Jr[.])?",
        Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS);
Matcher m = p.matcher(input);
while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group());
}
```

Output:

```
Paul Millsap
Al Horford
Tiago Splitter
Jeff Teague
Kyle Korver
Thabo Sefolosha
Mike Scott
Shelvin Mack
Kent Bazemore
Dennis Schröder
Tim Hardaway Jr.
Walter Tavares
Justin Holiday
Mike Muscala
Lamar Patterson
Terran Petteway
```

Comment: OK, fair enough, English is not my main language so I may be wrong, but I am not sure `Mr.` can be placed at the end of such series. Also from what I remember `Mr.` `Ms.` are titles (not part of name like `Jr.`) and they are placed at start. For now I will leave this answer as it is (I don't want to repeat other answer). Will try to update it if OP will provide example of data for which it doesn't work.

Comment: Thank you a lot, this does work. However, I changed \\w+\\s+\\w+(\\s+Jr[.] to \\S+\\s+\\w+(\\s+Jr[.] to include first names such as C.J.

Comment: Good for you. But I it would be nice if you would post HTML code which you parsed which contains these names. Maybe there is some easier way than regex.

Comment: @user4376182 I updated my answer with simpler Jsoup solution. I am printing found text but you can do what you want with it.

Answer (score 2):

You could do a basic "split every second space", then examine the next string to see if it has anything (like a period) that would indicate that it belongs to the previous string.  Works if things like Jr. have the period, wouldn't work if the punctuation isn't present

Answer (score 1):

Search for two words, and then search for any third word only if it ends in a `.` character:

```
\b(\w+ \w+\b(?: \w+\.)?)
```

Replace with `\1,`. [regex101.com example](https://regex101.com/r/yX2sM7/1)

Comment: What about "Joe Smith III"  or "Sue Ann Langdon"

Comment: All valid cases, but the OP would need to update with the actual cases. In that scenario, you could use multiple OR blocks: `(?: \w+\.| Jr| III| Sr)` and so on. Double first names like `Sue Ann` would break the regex.